# Get token from URL and send to post api with Axios Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Hi i need to take token from URL `http://192.168.178.25:8080/register?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI...`

and send a Post request on API for confermation account

I have tried this but on backend i've receive SyntaxError!

Someone can help me?

```js
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
    name: 'Register',
    data() {
        return {
            confirmation : false,
            somethingWrong: false       
        }
    },
    
    created: function() {
        axios.post('/api/users/validateRegister', null,{
            params: {
                registerToken: this.$route.query.token,
                state: this.$route.query.state
            }
        })
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
            this.confirmation = true       
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
            this.somethingWrong = true
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Using the this axios syntax will make a post request, not with body, but rather with query params, which is probably why you are getting a server error

Comment: I'm very awkward it's the first time I use vue and axios, can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is expecting JSON but you are sending something else.

Try running this in your browser console (devtools): `JSON.parse('asdasd')`.

How you are sending it right now:

```js
axios.post('/api/users/validateRegister', null,{
  params: {
    registerToken: this.$route.query.token,
    state: this.$route.query.state
  }
})
```

Will send a request that looks like:

`/api/users/validateRegister?registerToken=<token>&state=<state>`

To do a `POST` request with body according to [docs](https://github.com/axios/axios/tree/v0.25.0#axiosposturl-data-config), you do:

```js
axios.post(url[, data[, config]])
```

Which in your case means, assuming you need `registerToken` and `state` as part of body and not query parameters:

```js
axios.post('/api/users/validateRegister',{
  registerToken: this.$route.query.token,
  state: this.$route.query.state
})
```

Notice how there's no `null` in the 2nd param and no `params: {}`

---

You can also according to [docs](https://github.com/axios/axios/tree/v0.25.0#axiosconfig) do the following syntax:

```js
axios({
  method: 'post'
  url: '/api/users/validateRegister',
  data: {
    registerToken: this.$route.query.token,
    state: this.$route.query.state
  }
})
```

Comment: i try it but now on server i receive this "TypeError: tokens.validateTemporaryToken is not a function"

Comment: @Dan i dont see any variable called `tokens` in that backend code. Could be that.

Comment: after a sleepless night I solved, missing files in the backend server

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your server is throwing an error when trying to parse the body.

From your axios request, you're passing parameters instead of a body - you can see this by looking at the URL in the POST error on the right-hand side of your screenshot.

Instead, send the payload in the body like this;

```js
axios.post('/api/users/validateRegister', 
   {
      registerToken: this.$route.query.token,
      state: this.$route.query.state
   })
```

As you haven't provided any of the server-side code there may be something else going on we can't see.